# PHP create folder with specific path and permissions

Tags: php, directory

I need a way in PHP to create some folder if they do not exist.

So the code will have to first read the available folders, if the specific folder does not exist then it should create it.

The logic of the code would be:

```
$folderName = "user1";

If($folderName exists) {
exit;
}else{
create folder $folderName and chmod 777
}
```

How would I do it with PHP and Linux server + Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$folderName = "user1";

if ( !file_exists($folderName) ) {
    mkdir($folderName);
}
```

In `if` statement we check if folder does not exist (yes - with `file_exists` function) and if not, we create folder.

`777` chmod is by default.

Comment: + `chmod($folderName,0777);` But I really hate those 7's usually, 0770 is much more to my liking if the OP can use that...

Comment: `The mode is 0777 by default, which means the widest possible access.` ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: @hsz,Wrikken: drink deeper at the pierian well: "The mode is also modified by the current umask"

Comment: @symcbean: Ah, that would explain a lot. Me and my "_I've used mkdir so much I do not feel the need to read the manual_". Seems a good choice to take `umask` into account.